# MVC: can different controllers use the same view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am just starting to self teach MVC. I have seen simple examples where a controller passes a data object to a view and data can be shown on the view's aspx page. It looks like each controller is hardwired to a specific view(s). I can only add a new view to an existing controller but I can't use an existing view.

My question is, if I have multiple controllers, how can I allow each controller to use a single view. I am trying to avoid duplicatin view code. Also I have looked on the web for answers but this "simple" task appears to be very complicated. 
Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sharing Views](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/351720/sharing-views)  The third answer down has an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the view you would like to render like so:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View("/Path/To/ControllerView");
}
```

Leaving this value blank will result in the controller referencing the view based on the action name (in this case `Index.cshtml`

Comment: If you specify a path, then you have to also specify the extension .cshtml, .aspx, etc.. if you do not specify the path then you can just specify the view name without extension as found in the search path.

Comment: That worked,thank you, I looked at View's overload and it looks like you can specify a view explicitly like you said and also pass an object at the same time. View(string viewName, object model);

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch Are you sure? I appear to be able to specify the full path without the view's extension?

Comment: @JoeMighty - Unless this is something they changed in recent versions, this has always been a gotcha.. The reason is that the "search" code that searches the different installed view engines only gets called if not specifying a path.